# Many conditions if true in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have many attributes Boolean type , so if is true show **Yes** else show **No**.
Shall I do a condition "if" for each attribute or is there an other short method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators)** to achieve a shorter `if`-syntax in twig.

**example**:

```
# I'm creating an example array here

{% set user = { 'active' : true } %}

# Now, instead of ...

User is {% if user.active %}active{% else %}inactive{% endif %}.

# ... you can write:

User is {{ user.active ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}.
```

**output**:

> User is **active**.

Comment: is it possible to do a service with twig extension in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [implementing your own Twig Filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id3),

Something that looks like,

```
class YourProjectTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('booleanToString', array($this, 'booleanToString')),
        );
    }

    public function booleanToString($value)
    {
        if (!$value) {
            return "No";
        }

        return "Yes";
    }
```

Take a look at the [relevant part](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id3) of the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html),

- [Extending Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html)

This allows you to simply do,

```
{{ yourVariable.yourBooleanAttribute|booleanToString }} {# which shows "Yes" or "No" #}
```

**Update:**

For this specific need, I would recommend nifr's suggestion. But I'll keep this answer as it might help in case you want to apply some other specific logics within your template.

Comment: Hm isn't creating a twig extension - writing a class, registering it as a service, tagging it with twig.extension, testing it aferwards ... a bit **overkill** for such a simple operation? A twig macro ... maybe :) And what if you need different outputs ... like Yes/No, Active/Inactive, Cool/Uncool ... ? I don't think it's worth the effort in this case.

Comment: I always worked on application where extending twig was a real need. "writing a class, registering it as a service, tagging it with twig.extension" is done once and then allows you to manage all the filters/functions you need. So, I do agree with you in the case of extending twig only to address this particular need (question above) . But, let's say, you already extended Twig, adding the appropriate filter isn't that tedious.